# Visual Studio TFS add-in branch context menu

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, vsix

How can I add a custom entry to the context menu of a branch in the Source Control Explorer of TFS?

Answer (score 1):

To add context menu options you need to create an entry in a Visual Studio Command Table file. The simplest way to do this is to create a new extensibility project (you need to install the Visual Studio SDK first) - this has an example of how to add a custom command to an existing menu.

For more about vsix and vsct extensibility check: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164699.aspx

I also found this blog useful: 
http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/04/17/LearnVSXNowPart18A.aspx